# Last Line of Print Output missing notation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to sort a list of IPs, remove duplicates, and add a /32 to the end of each address. From my code you can see I'm 99.99% of the way there, except the last IP address of the output is missing the /32 notation. What am I missing that is causing this to occur?

I've not tried much, since I'm not sure what about the /32\n.join in the print line is ignoring the last address.

```
def laststep():
    src = '/tmp/masterlist.txt'

    with open(src, 'r') as f:
        ips = sorted(list(set(ipaddress.ip_address(line.strip()) for line in f)))
        print('/32\n'.join(map(str, ips)))
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
1.1.1.1/32
2.2.2.2/32
3.3.3.3/32
4.4.4.4/32
5.5.5.5
```

and what I'm looking to see is:

```
1.1.1.1/32
2.2.2.2/32
3.3.3.3/32
4.4.4.4/32
5.5.5.5/32
```

Comment: Because `join` works between consecutive strings, and the last string has no following string. In this case, it's probably easiest to just shove a `+'/32'` on the end and use string concatenation

Comment: What would I shove the +'/32' onto in the print line? Sorry, I'm still a python n00b.

Comment: `print('/32\n'.join(map(str, ips)) + '/32')`

Comment: Thanks. That was the final nail in the code that I needed. :-)